# Statistical comparisons for large sample sizes (n > 1000)

Tags: statistics

I am comparing the drug exposures across two different groups, consisting of 1000 simulated drug exposures per group. Drug exposures are continuous variables following a normal distribution.

I want to know if different doses yield a statistically significant difference in mean drug exposure across the two groups. I am observing that even if I calibrate "artificially" the doses to generate very similar mean exposures in both groups, all the statistical tests will always return very low p-values despite the very low difference in the groups' means. I guess this is due to the very large sample size (n = 1000 per group).

However, if I reduce the sample size (to 50 virtual drug exposures, let's say) the exposure is very sensitive to the sampling procedure because the samples are taken from a distribution with high standard deviation compared to the mean, and repeating the same analysis on different datasets can give very different means in exposure.

Is this a case where I should focus more on the "biological relevance" of the difference rather than the significance of such difference? Can you suggest a different approach to judging the relevance of the difference based on robust criteria?

Comment: I agree with your idea that large sample sizes make ANOVA more likely to detect differences. But be careful about assuming 'biological relevance' for differences is sample means with small sample sizes. // 'Robustness' is not a primary issue here.

Answer (score 1):

## Effect of Sample Size on Power of One-Way ANOVA

If you reduce sample sizes to 50 for each of the three treatment
groups, you may not have sufficient power to distinguish among
groups even if there are real differences among population means
of the three groups.

Just looking at the differences in sample
means might be misleading. Relatively large differences in
group sample means may not be real. You would have no way
to judge 'biological significance'.

**Three large samples.** Let's start with an experiment with three groups, and 1000
observations per group. Here are sample sizes, means, and
standard deviations for the three groups:

```
length(x1); length(x2); length(x3)
[1] 1000
[1] 1000
[1] 1000
mean(x1); mean(x2); mean(x3)
[1] 99.59983
[1] 100.0257
[1] 102.2992
sd(x1); sd(x2); sd(x3)
[1] 15.55448
[1] 15.09188
[1] 15.12943
```

The first two groups have means around 100, while the
third group has a slightly larger mean above 102. We look at a one-way
ANOVA to see if any of the differences are statistically
significant.

```
x = c(x1,x2,x3)
G = rep(1:3, each=1000)
boxplot(x ~ G, col="skyblue2", pch=20)
```

[image]

Boxplots show small differences among the groups, but these boxplots
don't show sample sizes so it is difficult to judge whether differences
are significant. However a one-way ANOVA find at least one highly significant
difference among the groups with P-value about 0.0001.

```
oneway.test(x ~ G)

        One-way analysis of means 
     (not assuming equal variances)

data:  x and G
F = 9.072, num df = 2.0, denom df = 1997.6, 
   p-value = 0.0001196
```

*Ad hoc,* we can look at Welch t tests to see the pattern of
differences among groups.

```
t.test(x1,x2)$p.val
[1] 0.534387
t.test(x1,x3)$p.val
[1] 8.644751e-05
t.test(x2,x3)$p.val
[1] 0.0007821064
```

In order to avoid 'false discovery', testing the same data
multiple times, we need to insist on P-values smaller than
about 0.01 in order to declare significant differences.
(See the Bonferroni method.) Even by that standard it seems
clear that Groups 1 and 2 both differ significantly from Group 3 (but not
from each other).

**Three small samples.** Now let's look at somewhat similar data, but with only 50 observations
from each group.

```
length(y1); length(y2); length(y3)
[1] 50
[1] 50
[1] 50
mean(y1); mean(y2); mean(y3)
[1] 101.8843
[1] 100.4236
[1] 98.38178
sd(y1); sd(y2); sd(y3)
[1] 16.67984
[1] 14.6449
[1] 13.79992
```

One might get the idea from these data that Group 3 has a smaller population mean than Group 1.

```
y = c(y1,y2,y3)
g = rep(1:3, each=50)
boxplot(y ~ g, col="skyblue2", pch=10)
```

[image]

Again here, the boxplots may seem to show differences among groups.
However, impressions are misguided that Group 3 may have a significantly
smaller mean than one or both of the other groups.
The one-way ANOVA shows no significant differences.
The P-value 0.51 is nowhere near significant.

```
oneway.test(y ~ g)

        One-way analysis of means 
     (not assuming equal variances)

data:  y and g
F = 0.67898, num df = 2.000, denom df = 97.435, 
  p-value = 0.5095
```

With this failure to reject the null hypothesis that all
three population means are equal, it would be wrong to
use Welch t tests to look for differences. Failure to
reject in the ANOVA has settled the matter.

```
oneway.test(y ~ g)

    One-way analysis of means (not assuming equal variances)

data:  y and g
F = 0.67898, num df = 2.000, denom df = 97.435, p-value = 0.5095
```

Actually, the `y`'s are just the first 50 observations from
the `x`'s above. So there really are *population* differences
among the `y`'s. But with only 50 observations per group,
we do not have a sufficiently powerful ANOVA to find them.
(It is just a curiosity of the randomness that the first 50
observations in `x1` happened to be unusually small, giving
the false impression that Group 3 values are smaller.)

You should always do a 'power and sample size' procedure at
the very start of an experiment in order to plan large enough
sample sizes to have reasonable chances of success identifying
real differences.

With population standard deviations as
large as 15, it is not realistic to find differences as small
as 2 or 3 among population means with only 50 observations per
group.

*Notes:* (1) Here is how the `x` and `y` values were sampled using R:

```
set.seed(2020)
x1 = rnorm(1000, 100, 15)
x2 = rnorm(1000, 100, 15)
x3 = rnorm(1000, 103, 15)

y1 = x1[1:50]
y2 = x2[1:50]
y3 = x3[1:50]
```

(2) You may have noticed that I used a version of one-way ANOVA
that does not assume equal variances. It uses a Welch-Satterthwaite
approximation. Accordingly, I used Welch t tests (also not assuming
equal variances) for *ad hoc* tests. For two-sample t tests, using the
Welch version has become standard. The Welch test is the default in
R and Minitab (to name two statistical programs I know about); you
have to ask specifically for a pooled test if you want to insist on it.